# How to change value of CSS variable as page scrolls gsap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have a css variable named --color. I want to change the value of this css variable as the page scrolls down. The scrolling of the page should "scrub" the value.

Example: --color starts out at rgb(255, 255, 255). As the page scrolls down, the value gets closer to and eventually reaches rgb(0, 0, 0) upon scrolling down all the way. When scrolling back up, the value should slowly advance back to rgb(255, 255, 255), reaching it by the time the page is scrolled up completely.

I have been trying to achieve this with GSAP but have yet to find any success, although I believe it must be possible with the library.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, here you go:

```
gsap.to("body", {
  "--color": "black",
  scrollTrigger: {
    start: 0,
    end: "max",
    scrub: true
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/WNOzWaM?editors=0110

By the way, there are dedicated GSAP forums at https://greensock.com/forums

Comment: Wow! This is awesome...would it be possible to have color stops? For example making --color go from red to green to blue as the user scrolls.

Comment: Absolutely. There are several ways. Here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/oNwamza?editors=0110

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I am not familiar with GSAP, but
here is [the link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables_javascript.asp) that describes how to get the computed styles and the property value of that style with JS.
You need to listen to scroll event and change the value of the css variable inside of the listener, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var root = document.querySelector(':root');
  var newColor = // do your color calculations here;
  root.style.setProperty('--color', newColor);
  }
```

here are some useful links.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful when you provide a code snippet to show what has already been attempted. Helps with specificity of the answer.

To give a general answer to your question, you can use `ScrollTrigger` to define the point at which the color changes. Define the markers where it should start changing and use properties such as `coloronEnter`, `onLeave`, `onEnterBack` to your callback to change the color.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an **average** calculation for your `rgb()` color that might be fine enough to go from light to dark and back. It is far to be perfect.

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body ");
const bodyHeight = document.querySelector("body").offsetHeight;
body.innerHTML = '<p style="position:sticky;top:0;">Body Height: ' + bodyHeight +  'px <br>Window Height: ' + window.innerHeight + 'px</p>';
const root = document.querySelector(":root");
window.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  let scroll = this.scrollY;
  let ratio = (scroll / (bodyHeight - window.innerHeight )  )  ;
  let rgbvalue = 255 -  ratio * 255;
  root.style.setProperty(  "--color", "rgba(" + rgbvalue + "," + rgbvalue + "," + rgbvalue + ")"
  );

  console.log(rgbvalue);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: var(--color, rgb(255, 255, 255));/* use defaul trgb(255, 255, 255) untill var is set from js */
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Had to change some numbers to get values under 255, but found your snipped to work!